# Convert server time to local time javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, timing

```
new Date(entry["startdatetime"]).toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")
```

How do i convert the server time into local time right now my time is coming as 18:30 equivalent to 6:30 PM.

My  `new Date(entry["startdatetime"])` value is

[image]

Whereas the server time is following:

[image]

Please could someone help

Comment: Send the server time as a UTC timevalue, then on the client you can use `new Date(timeValue)` to get the equivalent time in the client's timezone. Note that `toLocaleTimeString` is entirely implementation dependent so munging it using string methods may work in one browser but will certainly fail in at least one other.

Answer (score 0):

1. `<% new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date()) %>` this can be use to print `14-oct-2014`
2. Use  `my date:  &nbsp;<%= new java.util.Date() %>`  = out put should you found 
   `my date:  Tue Oct 14 10:52:39 IST 2014`. use this syntax I thinks this will resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertTime(serverdate) {
    var date = new Date(serverdate);
    // convert to utc time
    var toutc = date.toUTCString();
    //convert to local time
    var locdat = new Date(toutc + " UTC");
    return locdat;
}
```